# Adding to Epoch to find new Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, epoch

I'm working on a response from a script to work out an expiry date. The response is `7200` which I've been advised from the developer is an epoch value that should equate to 3 months. I've never used Epoch before so don't understand how this works?

The formula I've been given to use is `(created_at + expires_in) * 1000` which I've been advised will give me my new date.

I used `dtmNow = new Date(Date.now()).toISOString();` which returned `2016-08-23T06:33:35.936Z` which was correct, but when I tried `dtmExpires = new Date((Date.now()+7200)*1000).toISOString();` it returned `+048613-09-25T09:58:58.000Z`?

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: An epoch is a benchmark that things are measured relative to. The epoch for javascript time values is 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Differences are measured in milliseconds, 7,200 is 7.2 seconds after the epoch. There is no unit of measure where 7,200 of them equates to 3 months, which is about 7.776e9 milliseconds.

Comment: @RobG thanks! I changed my code to `dtmExpires = new Date(Date.now()+(7200*1000000)).toISOString();` and it returned `2016-11-14` which is 84 days :D If you post as an answer I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1):

[*Date.now()*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.now) returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch (the current time value). If you pass a number to the Date constructor, it's used as the time value for a new Date instance. In the following:

```
new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()
```

is exactly the same as:

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

i.e. you don't need *Date.now()*. If you want to add 3 months to a date, use Date methods:

```
// Get a Date for now
var now = new Date();

// Add 3 months
now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 3);
```

However, if it's currently 30 November then the above will attempt to create a date for 30 February, which will end up being 1 or 2 March depending on whether it's a in a leap year or not. So if the modified day in the month doesn't match the original, you can set it back to the last day of the previous month.

If you want to add (say) 90 days, then do that using the *setDate* and *getDate* methods similar to the following. This also takes account of daylight saving boundaries if you cross one, whereas setting the time value doesn't.

The SO console writes dates in UTC so take that into account when looking at the following results:

```js
function add3Months(d) {
  // Default to current date if d not provided
  d = d || new Date();
  
  // Remember current date
  var date = d.getDate();
  
  // Add 3 months
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 3);
  
  // Set the date back to the last day of the previous
  // month if date isn't the same
  if (d.getDate() != date) d.setDate(0);
  
  return d;
}

// Add 3 months to today
console.log(add3Months());

// Add 3 months to 30 November
console.log(add3Months(new Date(2016,10,30)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use the response given from the API I'm using, which is 7200, so I need to use the `Date.now()+(7200*1000000)` for it to be accurate if they change the response. It won't always be 3 months. It doesn't need to be 3 months exactly either. It's whatever they say. Thanks for this info though! Very helpful.